# I am using next-sitemap with my nextjs app. My website is multi-lingual. I want only the /en, /fr and not '/' pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Likewise, for cancel page, I don't want /en/cancel, /fr/cancel, but only /cancel . how do I do it?